# SQL Server 2005 xmldata decode

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, decode

I would like to decode the XML data column.

My table (`dailyReports`) has a column `col2` which contains more than one report

```
(col1)      (col2)
reportDate  xmldata
20130101    <t><m><s>234</s><ist>istanbul</ist><ino>17060</ino></m></t>    --1 xml rep.
20130102    <t><m><s>235</s><ist>izmir</ist><ino>12345</ino></m></t>...    --3 xml rep
20130103    <t><m><s>220</s><ist>ankara</ist><ino>98765</ino></m></t>...   --7 xml rep.
20130104    <t><m><s>234</s><ist>istanbul</ist><ino>17060</ino></m></t>... --4 xml rep.
20130105    <t><m><s>138</s><ist>edirne</ist><ino>17171</ino></m></t>...   --9 xml rep.
...
```

I would like to export the data; (Each report should go to a new line)

```
col1      col2  col3   col4
20130101  234   ist    17060 (first day 1 xml rep.)
20130102  235   izmir  12345 (second day 3 xml rep.)
20130102  220   ankara 98765 (second day 3 xml rep.)
20130102  138   edirne 17171 (second day 3 xml rep.)
```

...
7 lines for the third day
4 lines for the fourth day
9 lines for the fifth day
..

Answer (score 0):

Use nodes operator XQuery:

```
SELECT
  reportDate,
  T.t.value('(m/s)[1]', 'int'),
  T.t.value('(m/ist)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
  T.t.value('(m/ino)[1]', 'int')
FROM dailyReports D
CROSS APPLY D.xmldata.nodes('t') T(t)
```